# Pushing WKWebView to UINavigationController causes ui lag

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, webkit

I have two viewcontrollers. First one simply pushes second one to navigation controller. Inside second view controller I have `WKWebView` and it gets loaded in `viewDidLoad` method. Its content is local html file which is very simple. Only 3 buttons and one image.

Here is the problem. During the transition second view controller displays only white screen. After the transition WKWebView gets its content and shows html. There is about 0.5 seconds delay between transition end and content loading.

Is there a way to speed up or pre render `WKWebView`'s content loading?

Comment: I'd be interested to know if you ever found a solution for this issue.